# print the list from the name I searched until the end of the list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of names of players 
and next to the name there is the area
in which they are on the map.

An example of how the list is made:

```
ariko 252 121201 Human Oolacile

ron 228 Hollow Firelink Shrine

tanda 54 Human Sen's Fortress
```

I have created a program that tells me 
if the name I searched for is on the list. 
I would like the program to print me the list 
from the name I searched until the end of the list.
or even better if the program prints me only one 
line, from the name to the map area.
example:

drak    699 Human   120000  Darkroot Garden*

```
NUM=0
NomiDscm=open("C:/Risorse.py/UtentiDscm.txt", "r")
nomi=NomiDscm.read()
NomiDscm.close()
while NUM==0:
    NomeUtente=input(" Inserire il nome da cercare: ")
    if len(NomeUtente)<1:
        print(" ")
        print(" Inserire un NickName.")
        print(" ")
    elif NomeUtente in nomi:
        print(" ")
        print(" Utente Online.")
        print(" ")
    else:
        print(" ")
        print(" Utente Offline.")
        print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    NomeUtente=input(" Inserire il nome da cercare: ")
    with open('C:/Risorse.py/UtentiDscm.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            items = line.split()
            if items[0]==NomeUtente:
                print(items)
```

*I solved alone, by CLIPPER =).*